# Azure Frontdoor configure subdomain patterns for wildcard domain

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have FrontDoor instance *myFrontDoor* configured with wildcard domain (single CNAME record on *.myDomain.com* directed to *myFrontDoor.azurefd.net*).

Setup of frontdoor looks like:

```
Domain                  | Backend pools            | Rules
myFrontDoor.azurefd.net | backendPool-A            | rule-A
*.myDomain.com          | backendPool-B            | rule-B
```

I would like to set up rules in a way that:

- ruleA forwards all requests for a*.myDomain.com/* to backendPool-A (e.g. a1.myDomain.com, a2.myDomain.com)
- ruleB forwards all requests for b*.myDomain.com/* to backendPool-B (e.g. b1.myDomain.com, b2.myDomain.com)

I tried to setup a pattern in a rule to be like
`a*.myDomain.com/*` but it says that:
`Pattern is invalid, it must start with '/'` (by Azure Portal)

I tried to do this by Azure CLI as well but error occurs as well.

According to [Microsoft documentation for FrontDoor and wildcard domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/frontdoor/front-door-wildcard-domain#routing-rules) it should work.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No. Asked MS on github about this and only what they did was to change the documentation :) We solve this problem by registering all domains one by one and creating rule for each of them.

Comment: @GrzegorzM Isn’t your solution limited to max. 25 subdomains since FrontDoor supports max. 25 rules?